# How to ignore a letter while adding the sum of digits in a string?

Tags: python, string

This function receives as input one string containing digits, letters or special symbols.

The function should return one float number contaning the average calculated considering all the digits in the string. If there are no digits the function should return 0.0.

An example: `avgDigs('123a456')` should return `3.5`

So far I have

```
def avgDigs (st):  
    count = 0  
    total = 0  
    for i in st:  
        if st.isdigit():  
            count += int(i)  
            total += 1  
    print float(count)/total
```

How can I ignore letters and only add the digits?

Answer (score 4):

You need to check if the current item in the string is a digit, not the entire string. So you need

```
if i.isdigit():
```

instead of

```
if st.isdigit():
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just `filter` out the digits:

```
In [42]: filter(str.isdigit, '123a456')
Out[42]: '123456'
```

So, the values can be then directly converted to floats,

```
In [43]: map(float, filter(str.isdigit, '123a456'))
Out[43]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

And Python provides a funciton for finding the mean:

```
In [44]: mean(map(float, filter(str.isdigit, '123a456')))
Out[44]: 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more pythonic.

```
import re

def avgDigs(st):
    digits = re.findall("[0-9]", st)
    print reduce(lambda x,y:float(x)+float(y) ,digits,0)/len(digits)
```